# PHP SLIM DELETE issue get always success message

Tags: php, mysql, slim

When I run this script, I always get the success message `"successfully deleted"` even if the id did not exist and no records were affected. Any idea why? How can I fix this?

```
$app->post('/api/delete', function(Request $request, Response $response)   {

  $id = $request->getParam('id');

  $sql = "DELETE  FROM test WHERE id=:id";

  try{
      // Get DB Object
      $db = new db();
      // Connect
      $db = $db->connect();
      $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);

      $stmt->execute();
      echo '{"notice": {"text": "successfully deleted"}}' ;

    } catch(PDOException $e){
      //echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}}';
      return $response->withStatus(400)->write('{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}}');
    }
});
```

Comment: As long as the query executes, it won't throw an exception. In your case, it successfully executed, and it affected 0 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Need to use [rowCount()](http://php.net/manual/en/pdostatement.rowcount.php) there:-

```
$app->post('/api/delete', function(Request $request, Response $response)   {

  $id = $request->getParam('id');

  $sql = "DELETE  FROM test WHERE id=:id";

  try{
      // Get DB Object
      $db = new db();
      // Connect
      $db = $db->connect();
      $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
      $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);

      $stmt->execute();
      $count = $stmt->rowCount();
      if($count >0){
        echo '{"notice": {"text": "successfully deleted"}}' ;
      }

    } catch(PDOException $e){
      //echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}}';
      return $response->withStatus(400)->write('{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}}');
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 try{
  // Get DB Object
  $db = new db();
  // Connect
  $db = $db->connect();
  $stmt = $db->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->bindParam(':id', $id);

  $query=$stmt->execute();
  if($query)
     echo '{"notice": {"text": "successfully deleted"}}' ;
  else
     echo '{"notice": {"text": "Some Error Occured"}}' ;
} catch(PDOException $e){
  //echo '{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}}';
  return $response->withStatus(400)->write('{"error": {"text": '.$e->getMessage().'}}');
}
```